# Adobe Dynamic Tag Manager - Accessing information from click

Tags: google-analytics, adobe

My page has a list of links, with some associated information.

eg. Something along the lines of

```
<div class="listOfThings">
   <div class="Thing"> <a link here/> <specific thing A info here/> </div>
   <div class="Thing"> <a link here/> <specific thing B info here/> </div>
   <div class="Thing"> <a link here/> <specific thing C info here/> </div> 
</div>
```

In DTM, I want to be able to track a click on to any of those inner "Thing" divs, extract which thing was clicked, and pass that info to Google Analytics. I can get the click selector working fine, but I want to know how to extract the additional information on the click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be done inside of an Event Based rule. See image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyp8g.jpg

Event Type: Click

In the element tag or selector: div.things a
This is saying I want to track all click on any anchor tag inside a div with the class name of "things"

Then once you have done that you can reference the "this" scope.  You have use %% as a notation within the form fields for the GA code.  so %this.text% would pull in the text of the specific link selected:  %this.innnerHTML%, %this.href%  etc...